# Creating a pageViewController with a segmentController below navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm trying to create pageViewController which have several tableViewControllers however i want to create a navigation between the tableViews, so therefor i want a segmentController below the navigationController like this. the segmentController is created through a subclass and then in a toolbar? how can i add such a segmentController below in a pageViewController?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of libraries availabel, have a look

https://github.com/cemolcay/SlidingContainerViewController
https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

Comment: Okay but how do i add several tableViews to this scrollView?

Comment: hmmm the details you have given above are a bit vague to me, I didn't get it fully, "TableView to the scrollviews"? 
Meanwhile SlidingContainerViewController lets you add multiple Controllers in its container, you can design controllers and add TableViews in them the way you want, check USAGE on lib page to install it in your project